# How to display total in view page (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

I am just new to Codeigniter. I want to display the total sum of bill_rpt of this SQL query in the view page. here's the code

**this is my Model**

```
public function total() {
    $sql="SELECT bill_rpt
    FROM amilyar_bill
    WHERE bill_status = 1";
    return $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

**this is my Controller**

```
public function payments($token=''){
    $this->isLoggedIn();
    $data = array(
            // get data using email
        'token' => $token,
        'admin_info' => $this->model->getAdminInfo($this->session->userdata('email'))->row(),

        'notifications' =>  $this->model->notification_admin($this->session->userdata('email'))->result_array(),
        'notification' =>  $this->model->all_notification_admin($this->session->userdata('email'))->result_array(),
        'total' =>  $this->model->total($this->session->userdata('email'))->result_array(),

    );

    if ($this->session->userdata('position_id') == 2) { 
        $this->load->view('includes/admin_header',$data);
        $this->load->view('admin/reports/payments',$data);
    } else {
        $this->logout();
    }
}
```

**this is my View**

```
<h4 class="pull-right">Total:</h4>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Use ci `select_sum()` to get the sum

*Your `total` method should be like this :*

```
public function total()
{
   $this->db->select_sum('bill_rpt');
   $this->db->where('bill_status' , '1');
   $query =  $this->db->get('amilyar_bill');
   return $query->row()->bill_rpt;
}
```

*Your $data part in controller `payments` method should be like this :*

```
$data = array(
  'token' => $token,
  'admin_info' => $this->model->getAdminInfo($this->session->userdata('email'))->row(),
  'notifications' =>  $this->model->notification_admin($this->session->userdata('email'))->result_array(),
  'notification' =>  $this->model->all_notification_admin($this->session->userdata('email'))->result_array(),
   'total' =>  $this->model->total()
);
```

In `payments` view  part use $total like this :

```
<h4 class="pull-right">Total: <?=$total;?></h4>
```

Comment: I mean i want to total the value bill_rpt. bill_rpt has value of 4,698 and 748

Comment: how to call it in view page?

Comment: see my answer again just change ur total in $data like this  and use in view as in my answer

Comment: Done mate. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `num_rows()` method of Active Class.

`$query->num_rows();`

```
public function total(){
 $sql="SELECT bill_rpt FROM amilyar_bill WHERE bill_status = 1";
 $query = $this->db->query($sql);
 return $query->num_rows();
}
```

And in View,

```
<h4 class="pull-right">Total: <?php echo $total;?></h4>
```

Comment: I mean i want to total the value bill_rpt. bill_rpt has value of 4,698 and 748

Answer (score 0):

Try `SUM` function of MySql as:

**In Model**

```
public function total(){
$sql="SELECT SUM(bill_rpt ) as total_sum
FROM amilyar_bill
WHERE bill_status = 1";
return $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: i mean the sum of bill_rpt

Comment: Then you should use `sum` function of mysql

Comment: then how to call it in view page?

Comment: call in view as `$total['total_sum']`